# How can I raise my bed frame cheaply?

Tags: storage, bedroom

If the bed were a few inches higher, I would be able to store my suitcase beneath it. Is there anyway to raise it and still be able to support a person lying down?

I may be looking for [something like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000L3QBEK) though $20 seems a bit much for something that gives a few more inches and I'm in Canada. I've heard of using milk crates but wouldn't they break? If not, where would I get them from?

The bed has wheels and is for a single person.

Comment: This sentence confuses me "*$20 seems a bit much for something that gives a few more inches and I'm in Canada.*".  How does being in Canada affect the situation?

Comment: @Tester101 - Prices in Canada tend to be higher than they are in the USA, for various reasons.

Comment: Not sure this can be answered without knowing what kind of bed spring or current setup you have.  I see blocks being offered but this won't work without a very rigid bed base.

Comment: It turns out the product can't be shipped to Canada period.

Comment: I'll upload pictures asap.

Comment: Home Depot has some nice bed risers for under $10. I don't think you're going to get milk crates or cinder blocks for much less if you have to buy them. Google for "Bed Risers". Amazon, Bed/Bad/Beyond and other places have them too.
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Unbranded-Bed-Risers-4-Pack-6511-3349-BLK/203878106

Comment: Can you take the wheels off? That will give you more options.

Comment: I had a spare table. I folded up the bed frame and set it aside, then set the box spring and mattress on top of the table. This basically gave me another closet under my bed (and made all my rooommates jealous). This costs $0 if you happen to have an extra table. You may be able to find a table at a thrift store or garage sale for $30. It costs more than $20, but gives you more than a few inches, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your local hardware store and buy 4 of these. Maybe $1.50 each?
[image: Cinder Block]

Bring them home, and lay them on their side.

$6 and you have a very sturdy 8" lift.

If you need higher, buy 4 more.

If it is too heavy for you, pay a youngster $10 to haul them up the stairs. Still under $20.

Comment: @Celeritas:  Don't set the wheels on top of cinder blocks!  (it will be likely to roll off, stable, and could crack the block). Remove the wheel assemblies and set the frame directly on the blocks.

Comment: Wouldn't the middle of her bed sink in these?

Comment: Nothing has been said about the size of the bed, if it is wheeled, etc. But yes, I would recommend not keeping a wheeled bed on top of the blocks. Also, if there is a center support for your bed, buy more blocks.

Comment: If it is just a mattress then she would need like 20 blocks or it will be very lumpy.

Comment: @DMoore  At that point you can probably forget storing the suitcase as well. :(

Comment: Cinder blocks, no matter the orientation, would raise a bed more than a "few inches."

Comment: Regular bricks would work to raise the bread just a few inches.

Comment: Breezeblocks will hurt if you stub your toe.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go get yourself an 8' untreated 4x4 (~$10.00).

   [image: 4x4]
2. Determine how much higher you'd like the bed to be, then cut the 4x4 in appropriate lengths adding an inch to each length.
   For example:
   If you want the bed to be 4" higher, cut the 4x4 in 5" lengths.
3. using a spade or Forstner bit of appropriate size (just slightly larger than the bed frames feet, so the feet will fit into the hole), bore a hole to the depth of one inch.
   [image][image]
4. place the frame on the 4x4 pieces, such that the feet of the frame sit in the holes you bored.

***NOTES:***
*Make sure you use untreated wood.  Pressure treated wood may damage, and/or stain your bed frame and flooring.*

*I'm assuming you have a drill press and the appropriate bits, so the cost of the project only includes the lumber.*

*Making the leg extensions too high could cause the bed to be unstable, leading to property damage, injury, and or death.*

Comment: One inch is not much lateral support. I think you run the risk of tear-out. Also, drilling into the end grain and then putting lateral pressure on the wood could lead to splitting, even if the hole is deeper.

Comment: @bib You want a cheap solution, you *get* a cheap solution.

Comment: The 4x4 will cost him $8 and the forstner will cost $12, so there goes the $20!

Comment: @bib See the notes.  I'm assuming he already has the Forstner bit.

Comment: I have often spent $100 for tools for a $25 project (hoping I'd need them again!?)

Comment: Of course everyone has a forstner bit.  It is right next to my diamond grinder...

Comment: This what I did to raise my bed. I built a three-tier ziggurat of 2x4's and drilled a 1" diameter, 1/4" deep hole in the top to prevent the bed from rolling off. It has been stable for twenty years and several <4 magnitude earthquakes. A spade bit can be found for $2. The 2x4's were cast offs from previous projects.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to raise your bed is too use a product designed for the task. These [bed risers](http://www.thesleepshop.com/store/pc/G10-Deluxe-Bed-Riser-34p647.htm) from The Sleep Shop will do the trick. They're going to raise your bed about three inches but keep the sturdiness so there's no rocking! [image]
They aren't the prettiest things but, they'll work!

Answer (score 2):

We use a set of those lifters you linked for our king-size bed.  They work great.  I would NOT use milk crates, as their open frame isn't designed for point-weight support like a bed frame foot.

If you're looking for a low-cost lift of a couple inches, a small piece of lumber (4" length of 2x4, for example) would work fine.  Be aware, most basic bed frames have wheels, and can roll off blocks of wood.  This can be a bit shocking, as it's likely to happen when you're moving on/off the bed.  One advantage of the $20 lifters is they have a lip which traps the wheel.  They also interlock, so if you need to lift the bed a bit higher (2 lifters worth) it's still shear safe.

Whatever you place under the feet of the bed, make sure you raise ALL of the bed feet the same distance.  Larger beds (kings, some queens) have supports in the middle of the bed as well as corner supports; they must all be lifted equally.  Other than that, anything which will support the weight without collapsing will work.

(postnote)
The above applies to basic angle-brace steel frames.  More sophisticated/expensive frames which incorporated head or foot boards or other features may not be liftable this way.  Well...  the basic idea of "lift ALL the feet equally" should still apply, but you may have to do something to also lift the header/footer.  These concerns will be much more frame specific, and we'd need more information (pictures?) to properly answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a base.  I suggest you go to the local hardware store and get the thickest piece of plywood.  You need something that is the same size of your bed but rigid - actually have them cut it about 2 inches short lengthwise and widthwise so that the board is hidden on each side.  Bonus - look on craigslist for old bed frames being throw out, wood, old tables or whatever.  You have to look for stuff in your area and use your imagination a little.  You might need a circular saw (or beg the person throwing out the wood to cut whatever for you).  This could be free or $12 for the plywood at big box.

Then I would use milk crates.  How many you need depends on how stable you want your bed to be and how big your bed is.  A basic twin with a board under it can definitely be held by just 4.  You could add a couple in the middle and go 3 on each side if you want extra reinforcement.  You can get these for free at some recycling centers or supermarkets.

[image]

Myself I had a rig like this in college but used textbooks instead of milk crates.

Comment: finally a good use for those textbooks